# Is momentum of particles of pair annihilation same?

Tags: particle-physics, reference-frames, pair-production

I am currently studying pair production and I realized a very weird trend (Acc. to me) that the momentum of both of the particles is taken the same? When I tried it's math it was very complicated(and I don't know whether it was correct or not). Can someone tell me that is it just assumption? If someone can prove it (with math) it will really helpful.

Comment: It is convenient to study in the center-of-mass coordinates.

Comment: but my question is -is it important??

Comment: It makes the math easier, but it is just a coordinate/momentum transformation - the results are still general. The same is done when collisions are studied in classical mechanics or, e.g., when we solve the hydrogen atom in QM.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is conserved. So if the total momentum of the input particles is 0 then the total momentum of the output particles is also 0. For two particles this leads to opposite momenta, not equal.